# LnRen returning 'Account not found'

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

Using LnRen but receiving error response.  Error response directly below.  Checked the error mapping and error code doesn't exist on jha.dev.

```
<ErrCode>1</ErrCode>
<ErrCat>Error</ErrCat>
<ErrDesc>Account not found</ErrDesc>
<ErrElem>AccountId.AcctId AccountId.AcctType</ErrElem>
<ErrElemVal>Redacted/L</ErrElemVal>
<ErrLoc>LNRENEWADD</ErrLoc>
```

Loan account does exist on core.  Passing over the following values in the request.

```
<ns:AccountId Rstr="">
        <ns:AcctId JHANull="" Rstr="" SrchType="" MaskVal="">redacted</ns:AcctId>
        <ns:AcctType JHANull="" Rstr="">L</ns:AcctType>
        <ns:Ver_1/>
        </ns:AccountId>
     <ns:LnRenInfo>
        
        <ns:NxtPayDt JHANull="" Rstr="">2023-06-05</ns:NxtPayDt>
        <ns:PmtDayOfMonth JHANull="" Rstr=""></ns:PmtDayOfMonth>`your text`
        
        <ns:SemiDay1 JHANull="" Rstr=""></ns:SemiDay1>
        
        <ns:SemiDay2 JHANull="" Rstr=""></ns:SemiDay2>
        
        <ns:PmtTerm JHANull="" Rstr="">1</ns:PmtTerm>
        
        <ns:PmtTermUnits JHANull="" Rstr="">Months</ns:PmtTermUnits>
        
        <ns:PmtCode JHANull="" Rstr="">0</ns:PmtCode>
        
        <ns:PIAmt JHANull="" Rstr="">885.46</ns:PIAmt>
        
        <ns:PmtAmt JHANull="" Rstr="">885.46</ns:PmtAmt>
        
        <ns:MatDt JHANull="" Rstr="">2043-05-05</ns:MatDt>
        
        <ns:IntRate JHANull="" Rstr="" JHANA="">0.08</ns:IntRate>
        
        <ns:LnTerm>
           <ns:TermCnt JHANull="" Rstr="" JHANA="">240</ns:TermCnt>
           <ns:TermUnits JHANull="" Rstr="">Months</ns:TermUnits>
           
           <ns:Desc JHANull="" Rstr=""></ns:Desc>
           
           <ns:DaysCall JHANull="" Rstr=""></ns:DaysCall>
           <ns:Ver_1/>
           <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
        </ns:LnTerm>
        
        <ns:EffDt JHANull="" Rstr="">2038-05-26</ns:EffDt>
```

Expecting a success message.

Answer (score 0):

Found a resolution.  Loan was still in LTNEW and not LNMAST.